# CMake having problems in finding LIBLZMA

Tags: compiling

When I'm building GLOW in my Ubnantu 20.04, the CMake reports:
`-- Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET)  -- Could NOT find LIBAIO (missing: LIBAIO_LIBRARY LIBAIO_INCLUDE_DIR)  -- Could NOT find LIBIBERTY (missing: LIBIBERTY_LIBRARY LIBIBERTY_INCLUDE_DIR)`

and many more other libraries missing. I install them with apt-get install and every lib is ok except LibLZMA. It reports:
`-- Could NOT find LibLZMA (missing: LIBLZMA_HAS_AUTO_DECODER LIBLZMA_HAS_EASY_ENCODER LIBLZMA_HAS_LZMA_PRESET) (found version "5.2.4")`
I'm really wondering what's the problem since CMake does find LibLZMA but why there is still something wrong?
This problem has been worrying me for several days, eager to get an answer.Thanks.

Comment: `glow` https://github.com/pytorch/glow ..... **README.md** says `sudo apt-get install clang clang-8 cmake graphviz libpng-dev libprotobuf-dev llvm-8 llvm-8-dev ninja-build protobuf-compiler wget opencl-headers libgoogle-glog-dev libboost-all-dev libdouble-conversion-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev libgflags-dev libjemalloc-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev liblz4-dev libzstd-dev libbz2-dev libsodium-dev libfmt-dev` ............... Did you forget liblz4-dev ? ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem many days ago and forgot to take a look at this platform so I did not reply to you on time. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: This might be the cause of the problem because when I follow the instruction again, this problem is solved.